# Are trains from Narita Airport running on New Year's eve?

Tags: japan, tokyo, nrt

The trains from Narita Airport to Asakusa station runs normally on January first?

Comment: which train lines are you referring to? afaik all train services will be running on NYE but some lines may have reduced services, compared to normal

Comment: Skyliner or JR Narita Line? I'm not really familiar with all the trains in Japan.

Comment: New Years is actually a really busy time due to domestic and international travelers so expect congestion, but do expect these to run on nye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trains in Japan run on New Year's Eve, and January 1st.  For most of the day, they will operate with a weekend/holiday schedule; however, some lines expand their service to cover late-night and early morning "[hatsumode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatsum%C5%8Dde)" visits.  I doubt that the airport line sees any increase in service.

If you search hard enough, you may come across some information about Keisei's expanded service at New Years between Narita and Asakusa, as both of those areas are extremely popular for hatsumode.  Warning:  This is not for Narita Airport, but the not-so-nearby Narita Station.  This [press release (in Japanese)](https://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/kouhou/news/141204_01.pdf) was made last year on December 4, so it is reasonable to expect that you can get similar information around the same time this year.  They may include the airport in their expanded schedule, but I doubt it.